# How can I find out the size of a variable (in KB) to ensure an ajax GET request isn't too large?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function that continually adds data to an array based on the user's actions. The array is intended to be sent out via ajax to a website on *a different URL*, so i'll be using GET.

Since GET requests are limited in size, my plan is to have javascript monitor the array and send the data out when it approaches the max size of a GET request (I've read about 8kb).

I know that POST would be preferable but I need to send the array to another domain.

**How can I find out when the array contents are ~7kb so I can trigger the ajax request?**

Comment: FWIW: IE (at least up until 8, I don't know about IE9) [doesn't accept URIs of more than 2083 characters](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/max-url-length-in-ie8/d4d3f02c-bd50-4490-9409-4754455e3294).

Comment: What's the contents of the `Array`? `String`s?

Comment: This shouldn't work with AJAX if the security settings are correct (cross-domain scripting).

Comment: @pst Does the 2083 limit apply to URLs being invoked manually through JS? @alex the array has JSON objects which are converted to strings in preparation for the ajax request

Comment: @Valdislav - He can - google jsonP, that's why he's limited to a get request.

Comment: @Nathan, I wasn't aware of that. Though it sounds like a horrible hack, thanks for letting me know about it :)

Comment: @Vladislav Think about the fact that Google Analytics has to make a cross-domain js call on every site it's loaded on to phone home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array has to be serialized to a string for transmission, no? (*Somebody* has to do it, be it jQuery or whatnot).

I might be tempted to simply perform an incremental serialization and monitor the resulting *string length* -- that is, if there was no way to avoid this issue entirely :-) There is likely no performance issue with simply performing a full serialization and checking the resulting *string length*; just use an appropriate trigger/poll setup.

Happy coding.